# What uwsgi metric has "too many requests, not enough workers" metric?

Tags: uwsgi

I have a uwsgi app with one process one thread.
If I send a single request, the worker takes it. No problem. It usually takes around 200ms to return
If I start slamming it with like 100 simultaneous requests, there is some internal buffer (or queue) that gets filled up, but the one worker happily processes all requests, one at at a time.  The first one returns in 200ms, the next one in 400ms, the next one in 600ms, ect. etc.

I've enabled metrics in uwsgi:

```
    # Enable uwsgi metrics and push them to statsd server on the host:
    enable-metrics = true
    plugin = stats_pusher_statsd
    stats-push = statsd:$(LOCAL_IPV4):9191
```

And it produces TONS of metrics, but I can't find the metric that says "The size of the internal buffer (or queue) is X)".

I see that busy_worker goes to 1, idle_worker goes to 0, response_time goes up, (listen_queue is always at 0).

Maybe I have to enable more metrics somehow, or maybe there is no metric for this?